# Recommendation for Problems/Exercises Analysis Book/Notes

Tags: analysis, book-recommendation

While I mean ''Analysis'', it means Baby Rudin's top 8 chapter.

Comment: I usually recommend, for books, those with a list describing notation, chapter interdependence . This is a sign of someone  who took care to write a clear book. Problems with solutions too are a sign of effort towards writing a quality book.

Comment: Rudin's book itself has a full solutions set. If you're looking for something less daunting, try Apostol's book, which has solutions [here](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b89089/solution.html).